# Redis client hangs periodically when fetching data from redis cluster

Tags: node.js, redis-cluster

We have a nodejs application that uses redis as a cache.  Locally we use the stand-alone version of redis, and in production we connect to redis-cluster.  Recently we've noticed that redis hangs when we try to fetch data

example code:

```js
const redisClient = redis.createCluster({
  rootNodes: [{url}],
  defaults: {
    username,
    password,
  },
});

await redisClient.connect();


for(const obj of objArray){
  console.log('fetching data from redis')
  try{
    const objData = await redisClient.get(obj.name)
    console.log('done fetching data from redis')
  }catch(error){
    console.log('oops, there was an error')
  }
  console.log()
}
```

The output:

```
fetching data from redis
done fetching data from redis

fetching data from redis
done fetching data from redis

fetching data from redis
done fetching data from redis

fetching data from redis (then the app just hangs here)
```

Our application hums along nicely, then periodically it hangs when fetching data from Redis.  No error message, no exception, nothing in the logs.

After a period of time it starts up again, but it could take an hour or more before this happens.

Should I be checking if `redisClient.isOpen` on each call?